# laravel how I can access data of model through another model

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with laravel 8 and I have the following table structure.

### Users table

id,name,email,password,...etc.

### usersProfile table

id,bio,facebook,twitter,phone, user_id,...etc.

### projects table

id, title,details,image,user_id,....etc.

and I create the following relation in Project model

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
}
```

and have another relation in User model as following

```
 public function profile(){
    return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class,'user_id');
}
```

my question is how I can access user profile through project model? I read about hasOneThrough relation but I don't understand how to apply it in my code

Answer (score 0):

At the first you need to get a user then you can access the profile. so:

```
Project::with('user.profile')->get()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming in your `user_profiles` table you have `project_id` as a **foreign key**, Try :

```
public function userProfile()
    {
        return $this->hasOneThrough(
           UserProfile::class,
           Project::class,
           'user_id', // Foreign key on the projects table
           'project_id', // Foreign key on the user_profiles table
           'id', // Local key on the users table
           'id' // Local key on the projects table
    );
    }
```

Comment: no i don't have project_id in user_profiles i have only user_id

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
public function profile(){
    return $this->hasOne(UserProfile::class,'user_id');
}
```

To this:

```
public function profile(){
    return $this->belongsTo(UserProfile::class,'user_id');
}
```

Add this in your UserProfile model:

```
public function user(){
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}
```

Get projects and try this to check if works:

```
$project->user->profile;
```